# Regular Expression to split on comma

Tags: regex

I have this SQL sentence

```
SELECT regexp_substr(load, '[^,]+', 1, level) as name
   FROM dual
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(load, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL;
```

When I put `load := ',hello'` I need return  & `hello`. I have done the second, but i don't know how to return the first. This can be longer, like `load := ',hello,world'`, and return , `hello`,`world`.

Return after comma: `[^,]+`.

I know that this could be answered before, but I can't find that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `*` instead of `+`, because `+` would expect atleast one character where `*` won't.

```
(load, '[^,]*', 1, level)
```